# How to test a cancan ability for the create action with parameters?

Tags: ruby, rspec, cancan

My ability is this one:

```
def initialize(user)
  partner_id ||= user.partner.id
  can :create, Employee, :partner_id => partner_id
```

This is in the before block:

```
before(:each) do
  @employee = Factory :employee, role: "manager"
  @partner = @employee.partner
  @some_other_partner = Factory :partner
  @subject = EmployeeAbility.new( @employee )
end
```

My positive spec is this (This one passes):

```
it { @subject.should be_able_to(:create, Employee, partner_id: @partner.id ) }
```

My negative spec would be this (This one fails):

```
it { @subject.should_not be_able_to(:create, Employee, partner_id: @some_other_partner.id ) }
```

How should I declare the ability in such a way that I can test that the created employee belongs to a particular partner and not to some other partner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check an ability using an *instance* of a class rather than the class itself:

```
can? :create, Employee.new(:partner_id => 3)
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly?
I should pass an object with those attributes which will be set by the :create method. Easy :)